# Combine CSVs function adding random new line

Tags: python, csv

I have the following function:

```
def combine_csvs(csv_header, ends_with, directory):
   csv_list = []
   for item in os.listdir(directory):
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, item)):
         if item.endswith(ends_with):
            csv_list.append(item)
   csv_merge = csv_header

   for file in csv_list:
      csv_in = open(file)
      for line in csv_in:
         if line.startswith(csv_header):
            continue
         csv_merge += '\n' + line
      csv_in.close()
   return csv_merge
```

and 2 CSV files:

- 1_final.csv:

```
name,lowest,highest
John,14,53
Adam,13,60
```

- 2_final.csv:

```
name,lowest,highest
Mary,9,34
```

For some reason, when I run `print(combine_csvs("name,lowest,highest", "_final.csv", "."))` in the same directory as all of the CSV files, there is a blank line between John and Adam.

Comment: Sidenote: Best practice for opening files is using `with` like `with open(file) as csv_in: for line in csv_in: ...`. It's covered in the official tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
csv_merge += '\n' + line
```

You're adding a newline before each line and that's what causes the lines between the John and Adam line. So, get rid of the '\n' in that line of code:

```
csv_merge += line
```

Instead you need a '\n' after the header line. So, change this line from:

```
csv_merge = csv_header
```

to:

```
csv_merge = csv_header + '\n'
```

Comment: But what if the CSVs don't have trailing newlines? Then you'll end up with Adam and Mary squashed together. I think that's why OP added that in the first place. I think it'd be better to strip the lines and put them in a list. Then you can join them on newlines if needed.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't know whether a file has a trailing newline or not, it's better to strip() and then explicitly add a newline character, which is more work than adding a single newline at the end of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by simply changing `csv_merge += '\n' + line` to `csv_merge += '\n' + line.strip('\n')`.